# В Qt Designer исчезла левая и верхняя панели, как вернуть?

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

Qt Designer я разделил вид окон, чтобы они отдельно были, и пару дней назад пропали левая и верхняя панель. Если бы пропала только левая то через Вид -> Окна я бы сделал, но Вид(а) то нет
[image: Фото 1]

Также, эти окна не видно в панели задач и сварачиваются они очень странно
[image: Фото 2]

Пробовал переустанавливать, вроде не помогло (возможно сохраняются где-то настройки пользователя, хотя я и удалял папку из %APPDATA%\QtProject)

Comment: Andrey, ваш вопрос не понятен. Предоставьте ваш код и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: @S.Nick Кода нету, это стандартное приложение Qt Designer - редактор файлов .ui, оно и сломалось

Comment: @Andrey, судя по исходному коду дизайнера, это конструктор QSettings: `m_settings(qApp->organizationName(), settingsApplicationName())` настройки для винды надо искать в реестре, организация `QtProject`, аппликация: `Designer`

Comment: @PavelGridin, поискал в реестре с помощью Registry Finder, поудалял все где есть Qt Designer, все вернулось на свои места. Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.